# Xamarin Firebase PhoneAuth

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I need to create a Xamarin app (Not forms, but separated iOS and Android projects) that has Firebase Phone Auth. Most documentation indicates that there is support for Facebook Auth, but I need PhoneAuth as well.

I've found Xamarin.Firebase.Auth and apparently it has support for it, but I am not able to implement it nor I see any documentation on which interface should I use for it.

Answer (score 7):

Both Android and iOS require setup in the Firebase console and platform specific application setup, so the **Google Firebase Auth docs are a required reading** and the user needs to notified about phone usage/cost per your app's various countries of distribution legal requirements (noted in the Firebase docs...), iOS needs APN notifications setup, etc...

#### Android via `Xamarin.Firebase.Auth` Sample:

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

```
PhoneAuthCallbacks phoneAuthCallbacks = new PhoneAuthCallbacks();
PhoneAuthProvider.Instance.VerifyPhoneNumber("555-555-5555", 60, TimeUnit.Seconds, this, phoneAuthCallbacks);
// You can now obtain a user credential via the verification code and verification ID and
```

// sign the user in via the credential (see the OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks)

Sample PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks class:

```
public class PhoneAuthCallbacks : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
{
    public override void OnVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential)
    {
        // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
        // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
        //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
        // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
        //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
        //     user action.         
    }

    public override void OnVerificationFailed(FirebaseException exception)
    {
        // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
        // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
    }

    public override void OnCodeSent(string verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken)
    {
        // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
        // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
        // by combining the code with a verification ID.
        base.OnCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
    }
}
```

#### iOS via `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Auth` Sample:

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

```
var verificationID = await PhoneAuthProvider.DefaultInstance.VerifyPhoneNumberAsync("555-555-5555", null);
// You can now obtain a user credential via the verification code and verification ID.
// Now you can sign the user in via the credential
```

Comment: Could you, please, tell how to get access to the activity inside callbacks (we pass it as the third argument to VerifyPhoneNumber)?

Comment: dont forget to put `+1` before `"555-555-5555`, else it wont going to work