# Firebase Phone Auth on Xamarin.Form

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

I configured Firebase Phone Auth on my application. But there was a problem: SMS does not come to the number that is used on the phone. If you send SMS to another number, then everything works fine. What is the reason for this problem? The following are the classes implementing Phone Auth
My auth callback:

```
public class AuthCallbacks : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
{

    public override void OnVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential)
    {
        try
        {
            string smsCode = credential.SmsCode;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("onVerificationCompleted " + smsCode);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("onVerificationCompleted " + credential);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public override void OnVerificationFailed(FirebaseException exception)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("onVerificationFailed: " + exception);
    }

    public override void OnCodeSent(string verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
            VerifyCode.Code = verificationId;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("onCodeSent " + verificationId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

my Authenticator class

```
 public class Authenticator : IAuthentication
{
    string verificationID;
    public void RegsiterWithPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            verificationID = PhoneAuthProvider.DefaultInstance.VerifyPhoneNumberAsync(phoneNumber, null).Result;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("VerifyPhoneNumber");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    public void VerifySignInCode(string code, INavigation Navigation)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("VerifySignInCode");
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.DefaultInstance.GetCredential(verificationID, code);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(credential);
        SignInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilePage());
    }

    private async void SignInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential)
    {
        try
        {
            await Auth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: We need to implement Firebase PhoneAuth on specific platform ,  which platform did you develop on ? iOS/ Android ? Refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49395045/8187800

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT i develop on android platform